# How can I mix variables and wildcards in fish?

Tags: wildcards, variable-substitution, fish

I have a value stored in a variable that I want to use as part of a wildcard, like this:

```
set extension (somecommand)
cp *$extension ~/filezone
```

But the `*` prevents the variable from being dereferenced. How can I use the value stored in a variable as part of a wildcard?

Answer (score 2):

Your `somecommand` is probably returning nothing. Check `count $extension`, and I bet it's zero.

This does work:

```
$ touch a.foo b.foo c.bar
$ set extension foo bar
$ ls *$extension
a.foo  b.foo  c.bar
```

But if your variable is an empty list, `*$extension` expands into nothing.